# Lists and Pointers in C

Tags: c, list, pointers

I have a problem with lists and pointers, let me explain.
let's define a list like this:

```
typedef struct list *LIST;
typedef struct node *link;
struct list{link head; int n;};
struct node{Item val;link next;};
```

where `n`  is the number of nodes and LIST is a pointer to struct list (I have to do that because I want to make an opaque pointer to the list, in my homework the LIST pointer would go in the `.h` and the `structs` would go in the `.c` but that's not the problem, and I know I should avoid declaring pointer like that).

The Item type is also declared via an opaque pointer, so I have something like this:

```
typedef struct info *Item;
struct info{char *name;int N};
```

my problem is that I don't understand how to insert stuff in this lists. (so I would like to add an Item type to the lists, but I can't because Item is a pointer so, for example if a try to do this:

```
//the lists is already initialized and let's say we want to add 3 nodes
Item x=malloc(sizeof(*x));`
x->name=calloc(10,sizeof(char));
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   fscanf("%s",x->name);
   fscanf("%d",x->N);//this is a random number
   ListInsert(L,x);
}
```

this is what i have in ListInsert():

```
void ListInsert(LIST L, Item x){
link z,p;
if(L->head==NULL)
   L->head=newNode(x,L->head);
else{
for(z=L->head->next, p=L->head;z!=NULL;p=x, z=z->next);//i know a tail would help 
p->next=newNode(x,z);
}
}
```

And this is what I have in newNode():

```
link newNode(item x,link next){
link z=malloc(sizeof(*z));//should control the allocation was successful I know
z->val=x;
z->next=next;
return z;
}
```

Whenever I modify the value `x`, I'm actually modifying what the head and everything points to, that's my problem, what could be a solution? maybe make an array? pointers can sometimes be so hard to understand, for example should I allocate `z->val->name`?

Comment: "*Whenever i modify the value x*". Which `x`? There are multiple `x` variables throughout the code. And why would that change the head? The question is very unclear. Instead of telling it like a story with incomplete code snippets please provide complete code as a [mre] and give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: when i modify the value of x in the for cycle, where i acquire the values, don't i technically also change the value of head becayse head points to the pointer X?

Comment: You *do not* need to use typedefs (e.g. `LIST`) to have opaque pointers.  In fact, the two considerations are not related in any way.

Comment: And hiding pointer nature behind a typedef is poor style.  It tends to confuse much more than it helps.  Indeed, you seem to be suffering to some extent from exactly that confusion.

Comment: Giovanni Giordano, Avoid `fscanf("%s",x->name)` with no width limit.  Use `fscanf("%9s",x->name)` and check return value of all `fscanf()` calls.

Comment: BTW, Good use a sizeof to the referenced object rather than type `x=malloc(sizeof(*x))`.  Could do the same with `x->name=calloc(10,sizeof(char));` --> `x->name=calloc(10,sizeof x->name[0]);`.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the tips! I'm new here so sorry if i make some mistakes.

Comment: Reading the first few lines of the question: `struct list{link head; link n;};` ... *where `n` is the number of nodes...* The `n` can't be the number of nodes, it is a pointer to `struct node`.

Comment: What is `z!=NULL<0` supposed to do?

Comment: Giovanni Giordano, There are times to hide the fact a type is a pointer like with `typedef struct list *LIST;`, but for a learner - don't do that until you know why is is usually poor.  Instead `struct list{link head; link n;};` --> `struct list{struct node *head; struct node *n;};`

Comment: nothing, it's a typo i'm sorry, it is supposed to be  just z!=NULL.

Comment: also, n should be int, i fixed the code

Comment: The best way in future to avoid those typos is to prepare a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows what you tried, and then copy/paste the exact code into the question. It's also a lot harder for readers to examine code when it is fragmented.

Comment: I have a nagging suspicion that `typedef struct foo bar;`, when no `struct foo` is in scope yet, creates an *entirely new* `struct foo` that is *not* the same as any `struct foo` later defined. For avoidance of UB and confusion you should define each `struct foo` before any `typedef` that references it.

Comment: Nope, @mlp, there can be only one `struct foo` in any given scope.  The appearance in a `typedef` *does* declare that type (as an incomplete structure type), just as `struct foo;` would do, but any later declaration (including a definition) of that type in the same scope (re)declares the same type.  There is no UB risk involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say ...

> Whenever I modify the value `x`, I'm actually modifying what the head and everything points to, that's my problem, what could be a solution?

... I think you're talking about this code:

> ```
> Item x=malloc(sizeof(*x));`
> x->name=calloc(10,sizeof(char));
> for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
>    fscanf("%s",x->name);
>    fscanf("%d",x->N);//this is a random number
>    ListInsert(L,x);
> }
> ```

Indeed, you have allocated only one `struct info` and assigned `x` to point to it.  You have added that one `struct info` to your linked list three times, and also modified it several times.

Supposing that your objective is to add three distinct objects to the list, the solution starts with allocating three distinct objects (else where would they come from?).  Since each one has a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, you will also want to allocate a separate array for each of those.  The easiest way to achieve that would be simply to move the allocations into the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   Item x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
   x->name = calloc(10, sizeof(char));
   fscanf("%s", x->name);
   fscanf("%d", x->N);  //this is a random number
   ListInsert(L, x);
}
```

If you are permitted to modify the structures involved then you could also consider making the `name` element of `struct info` an array of suitable length instead of a pointer.  That's a little less flexible, but it would mean that you need only one allocation for each item, not two.

Comment: Perfect, this answered my question thanks a lot, i'm still new with programming and i have to understand pointers good because my exam is within a month, so i really appreciate this community and the way you guys try to help, and i also get to learn a lot!